# How to keep column size fix when text content changes?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create a table with four columns, that fills all the width of the screen. I will put some text that will change according to user input, and I want the four columns of the table to keep the same width whatever text I put into them, how could I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `layout_width="0dip"` and `layout_weight="1"` in every column.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your table layout something like this :

```
    <TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stretchColumns="*" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:longClickable="false"
            android:text="sdf" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/editText4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:text="sdfasdfsdfsdf" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/editText3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:text="sdsd" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:text="asdfasdfasdfasf" />

    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

[image: Fixe Size]

Comment: If you don't set `layout_width="0dip"`, your proposal doesn't work. Please, refer to my answer above.

Comment: How can you say that it will not work? Have you tried my code?

Comment: Yes, use TextViews with different text lenghts instead of EditTexts (according to @Paolo's question), and you will check how your code doesn't work.

Comment: This is what I did and it doesn't work. Moreover I do not want to use EditText (which I think do not change size depending on their content), but TextView.

Comment: Yes its working with TextView also. I have updated my code and added a screenshot.. Now what you say?

Comment: Let me be clearer... Your layout "works" just because you are setting the same EMS value to all the columns (and no matters the value, it has only to be the same in all of them). It has no sense to set an arbitrary EMS value to every column when you are expecting layout_weight to do the work. Semantically your approach is NOT correct, but nice try. The recommended way to do this is to put all layout_widths to 0 and then let layout_weight to do the work, you are misusing the EMS property.